# Reading from disk in tests with NodeJS - sync vs async

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have a suite of tests which reads data from local files.
I can implement it via `fs.readFileSync` or with `fs.readFile`. If my test runner, `jest`, runs tests in parallel in a pool of child processes:

> Tests are parallelized by running them in their own processes to maximize performance.

Does it mean I can use the `synced` version of `fs` methods without a performance hit?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFileSync` is a blocking code it will block the event loop unless the file reading is completed . So yeah performance wise it lies behind the asynchronous version.

What you can do ?

1-If you want to work in a more synchronous like environment ,promisfy `fs.readFile()` using (util library) and use in `async await`

2- Use a normal callback

And these are tests ,so performance issues don't matter that much but in production they will .

Look the docs [here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/)

Answer (score 0):

No, and Yes,

If you are doing something with data post reading the file, then you will need to use it Sync or via callback(or promise/async-await)

Let's try to understand with the example

reading file takes 300 ms

If you are not doing anything you can save this 300ms by going async way, But mostly you have to do something with that data hence you are reading it, so you will have to read it in sync and invest 300ms (going via async and callback/promise/async-await is same thing)

Comment: Anything that is blocking the event loop is a performance hit

Comment: If it is the only purpose of your application, then it is meant for it :p